# "Cannot find WebSpace" error when publishing with Microsoft Azure CLI

Tags: git, azure

While going through one of the tutorials I got the error below when publishing a Web app to my Azure account.What is a WebSpace and Why is Azure looking for one? I don't have this item listed as a resource anywhere in my Azure dashboard nor can I find a way to create it.

```
E:\MyDevProjects\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\app-service-web-html-get-started>azure site create GregoryJMyWebApp --git --gitusername GregoryJ
info:    Executing command site create
+ Getting sites
error:   Cannot find WebSpace with name SouthCentralUSwebspace.
error:   Error information has been recorded to C:\Users\GregoryJ\.azure\azure.err
error:   site create command failed
```

Comment: does this happen when deploying to any location or not?

Comment: I faced this issue, and this link helped me: https://github.com/Azure/azure-xplat-cli/issues/1646. My solution was to go into .azure folder in my home folder, search through JSON files with names like `spaces.{someGuid}` and delete from them webspace with name it complains about. After restarting `Azure CLI` it worked without problems. Some suggestions at the link were to remove .azure folder completely and upgrading `Azure CLI`, but I didn't try this.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the tutorial you are following?